# Powershell get-childitem env:path returns ellipsed one line, how to have something useful?

Tags: powershell

I want to know what is the content of my path variable, so I ran this command:

```
D:\> Get-ChildItem env:path

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Path                           %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\java\jdk\javaFX2.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\serve...
```

The problem is that the result is quite useless.

How can I have it plain text and without ellipsis ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything in powershell is an object. If you want to get the Value of the Path environment variable you have to access that:

```
(Get-ChildItem env:path).Value
```

Comment: I was aware of the object orientation of powershell, but I did not have a clue about the .Value to get a text representation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Normal object oriented stuff. Most every language that I am aware of uses dot notation to access the properties and methods of an object. In this case the only tricky bit is that you are accessing a property of an anonymous object rather than assigning it to a variable then accessing it like this: $foo = Get-ChildItem env:path; $foo.Value

Comment: is there an alternative something like `$object | get-childitem env:path | format-list` ?

Answer (score 3):

Below command shows the full PATH info instantly.

```
PS D:\> $env:path
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is better?

Comment: This is not a better solution but showing PATH value without ellipsis. I changed my comments to avoid confusion.

Comment: This doesn't show the full path, either, if your path is longer than 2452 characters. PowerShell _always_ truncates it.